# curl issue with sites that do not support Secure Renegotiation

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.2, pci-compliance

Context:

Server: Debian 8.6

curl 7.38.0-4+deb8u11

libcurl3:amd64                 7.38.0-4+deb8u11

openssl                        1.0.1t-1+deb8u8

CASE 1 (KO)

When I try to connect to a website that DOES NOT SUPPORT Secure renegotiation using curl by command line I am always getting this error:

Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to xxxxx

This the complete output of the command:

curl -v --tlsv1.2 xxxxxxxxx

- Rebuilt URL to: xxxxxxxxxx
- Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
- Trying XXXXXXX...
- Connected to xxxxxxxxxxxx (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: none

  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to xxxxxxxxxx:443
- Closing connection 0

curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to xxxxxx:443

Additional info: the remote website does not support secure renegotiation (I checked with openssl s_client -connect domainname:443).

It looks like curl always tries to perform the SSL handshake using SSLv3 and the server immediately refuse connection not performing any renegotiation.

CASE 2 (OK)

When I try to connect to a website that DOES SUPPORT Secure renegotiation using curl by command line I am able to connect.

This the complete output of the command:

root@web1:~# curl -v --tlsv1.2 XXXXXXX

- Rebuilt URL to: XXXXXX
- Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
- Trying XXXXXXX...
- Connected to XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX) port 443 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: none

  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
- SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-GCM-SHA384

Additional info: the remote website supports secure renegotiation(I checked with openssl s_client -connect domainname:443).

It looks like curl always tries to perform the SSL handshake using SSLv3, then the server performs a renegotiation and curl accepts the new ssl protocol version (tlsv1.2).

The root cause looks like curl is ignoring the option --tlsv1.2 or am I wrong?

I already updated packages to latest version (Debian 9 is not an option).

Any suggests?

Thank you

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you find any solutions?